# How do I handle the wrong number of method arguments?

Tags: ruby, string, activerecord

I'm working on a URL shortener and attemtping to convert the URL ID, which is a number, into a string, using base 36.

I'm receiving the error listed below the code:

```
def self.create_link(original)
  url = Url.create(:original => original)
  if Link.first(:indentifier => url.id.to_s(36)).nil? or !DIRTY_WORDS.include? url.id.to_s(36)
    link = Link.new(:identifier => url.id.to_s(36))
    link.url = url
    link.save
    return link
  else 
    create_link(original)
  end
end
```

I'm receiving the following error:

```
wrong number of arguments(1 for 0) file: tinyclone.rb location: to_s line: 91
```

When I researched the error, I found someone who mentioned that this error is common when you attempt to pass in parameter values when a method doesn't accept them. The error is specifically referring the following line.

```
if Link.first(:indentifier => url.id.to_s(36)).nil? or !DIRTY_WORDS.include? url.id.to_s(36)
```

Comment: btw you have iNdentifier as well as iDentifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the type of `url.id`?

I think your expecting it to be a `FixNum` whose `to_s` method accepts a radix, but you're getting something else instead... maybe a string containing a number? (e.g. `"1234"`)

Anyway, the method seems to require no arguments and you are passing `36` nevertheless

EDIT:

Can't find the reference to the class you pointed out (`Serial`), but this might be worth a try:

```
url.id.to_i.to_s(36)
```

Comment: In the model, it's defined as 'Serial' (an auto-incremented value).

Comment: Definitely worked! Thanks so much. I'm working with sinatra and datamapper which indicates PKs in models with the word 'Serial'. Working through tuts in a book published in 08' and have been having so many problems. Thanks again.

Comment: oh I see, well glad to be of help. I think you should have tagged this as `datamapper` and not as `activerecord` (no wonder why I didn't find a reference to `Serial` :) )

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see right away is:

```
if Link.first(:indentifier => url.id.to_s(36)).nil? or !DIRTY_WORDS.include? url.id.to_s(36)
link = Link.new(:identifier => url.id.to_s(36))
```

Notice that in the first line you have `:indentifier` and in the second it's `:identifier`.

Otherwise, I agree with @Pablo Fernandez's answer that it's probably tied to the type of `id`.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 models, but take full responsibility on the one of them only. please take a look at code separated logic:

```
# Link model
def self.create_link(original)
  url    = Url.create(:original => original)
  url_id = url.encoded_id

  find_or_create_by_identifier!(:identifier => url_id)
end


# Url model
def before_validate_on_create
  if url.id.to_s.include? DIRTY_WORDS
    self.errors.add(:base, 'the url is invalid')
  end
end

def encoded_id
  url.id.to_s(36)
end
```